# How to get a step plot using geom_step with different colors for the segments

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a step plot with different segment colors. I tried the following, but this only shows the last segment:

```
library(ggplot2)

mcgwh <- structure(list(Technology = c("FOS", "WOOD", "NUCL", "HYD", "HYDS","EWI", "WPV", "WPV"), MC = c(0.00909452733164008, 0.0216749226571617,     0.0473803148589957, 0.05619182757182, 0.070613003340574, 0.0854965730717766,     0.156860794757306, 0.156860794757306), Capacity = c(0, 1190.45103330156,     1419.2619999981, 27551.2619999981, 44237.2619999981, 65110.2619999981,     66943.2619999981, 67990.7380000019)), .Names = c("Technology", "MC", "Capacity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 8L))

ggplot(data = mcgwh, aes(x = Capacity) ) +  geom_step(aes(y = MC,colour = factor(Technology)))
```

Comment: You mean you want to connect the points with different colors like `ggplot(data = mcgwh, aes(x = Capacity) ) +  geom_path(aes(y = MC,color = factor(Technology),group=1))`?

Comment: The answer above works if you simply wanted direct line path from each point, the answer I provided below if you want steps.

Comment: Yes and no. With the solution by R.S. I can do the following and have the vertical lines be black and the horizontal lines colored. With your example, I don't manage that: ggplot(data = mcgwh2) +  geom_path(aes(x = Capacity, y = MC, group = 1)) + geom_path(aes(x = Capacity, y = MC, colour = Technology))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you cannot easily do this in `geom_step` by assigning `aes(colour = factor(Technology)`.  You have 2 options:

Use `geom_step` and `geom_point` in combination, with `geom_point` taking on the aes(colour = factor(Technology).

```
ggplot(data = mcgwh, aes(x = Capacity, y = MC)) +  geom_step() + geom_point(aes(colour = Technology))
```

[image]

If you want step lines color coded by Technology, you will have to create dummy interval entries with (x=Capacity, y=MC) points that will connect horizontally from the preceding point and vertically to the next point.  You can do so by repeating Technology (label) and MC (y variable) each 2x from 1:(nrow(mcgwh)-1) and Capacity (x varicable) each 2x from 2:nrow(mcgwh)

```
mcgwh2 <- cbind.data.frame(c(rep(mcgwh$Technology[1:(nrow(mcgwh)-1)], each=2), mcgwh$Technology[nrow(mcgwh)]), c(rep(mcgwh$MC[1:(nrow(mcgwh)-1)], each=2), mcgwh$MC[nrow(mcgwh)]), c(mcgwh$Capacity[1], rep(mcgwh$Capacity[2:nrow(mcgwh)], each=2)))
colnames(mcgwh2) <- c("Technology", "MC", "Capacity")
ggplot(data = mcgwh2) + geom_path(aes(x = Capacity, y = MC, colour = Technology, group=1))
```

[image]

Or alternatively

```
ggplot(data = mcgwh2) + geom_step(aes(x = Capacity, y = MC)) + geom_line(aes(x = Capacity, y = MC, colour = Technology))
```

[image]

Comment: THanks! What does the group = 1 does, or where can I find the documentation on that?

Comment: @user3270634 group = 1 indicates a single line connecting all the points.  http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied, so it can be marked.